# Devolver datos de un registro luego de haberlos eliminado en un procedimiento almacenado SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transacciones

comunidad estoy haciendo un procedimiento almacenado con una transacción, pero quiero que al momento que elimine, el registro con el Id, recuperar estos datos del registro luego de haberlos eliminado, para devolverlos en un select como resultado, sé que, en los Triggers, se pueden recuperar de la tabla `deleted`, pero no se si hacer esto mismo dentro de un procedimiento almacenado, me funcionaria igual,

Este es mi código,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_INS_GENDER
(
     @GenderId CHAR(1)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    BEGIN TRY

        DELETE
        FROM Genders 
        WHERE GenderId = @GenderId;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION 

        SELECT
              GenderId
             ,GenderName
             ,CreateBy
             ,CreationDate
             ,ModifiedBy
             ,ModifiedDate
        FROM deleted
        WHERE GenderId = @GenderId;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END
    END CATCH
END;
GO
```

Agradecería sus comentarios,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, puedes usar `deleted` pero mediante la cláusula [`OUTPUT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) de la siguiente forma:

```
DELETE
    FROM Genders 
    OUTPUT deleted.GenderId,
           deleted.GenderName,
           deleted.CreateBy,
           deleted.CreationDate,
           deleted.ModifiedBy,
           deleted.ModifiedDate
    WHERE GenderId = @GenderId;
```

No estás limitado solo a mostrar los datos, sino que podrías insertarlos en una tabla de auditoría, lo cual es bastante más recomendable que retornarlos desde el Sp.

```
DELETE
    FROM Genders 
    OUTPUT deleted.* INTO GendersLog
    WHERE GenderId = @GenderId;
```

Podrías crear una tabla `GendersLog` con la misma estructura de `Genders` para registrar las filas eliminadas, incluso podrías agregar nuevas columna para registrar fecha y usuario de la eliminación.

Comment: Si entiendo tu sugerencia, con lo de crear la tabla de logs, pero como no se van a manejar mas de 100 registros en esta tabla, no lo veo necesario, lo que quiero es devolver la información, para que el WebApi me devuelva como quedo el objeto y no hacer un select nuevamente a la tabla, pero muchas gracias por tu sugerencia